# Redirect Joomla URL with Query String and Language Code

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla, url-rewriting

I have the following redirects that I want to do.

```
/en/?Itemid=829 to /en/?Itemid=830
/ch/?Itemid=829 to /ch/?Itemid=830

/en/?Itemid=818 to /en/?Itemid=820
/ch/?Itemid=818 to /ch/?Itemid=820
```

My rewriterule are below and not working, please tell me what is wrong. Thanks.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Itemid=829$
RewriteRule ^Itemid=829$ /?Itemid=830 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Itemid=818$
RewriteRule ^Itemid=818$ /?Itemid=820 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Joomla has a native Redirect tool that can take care of this. Writing htaccess rules is more for if you have a general rule set that needs to be followed with URL's (remove .php, add www., etc)

Components => Redirect

Comment: I tried. I put Source: /en/?Itemid=829, and Destination: /en/?Itemid=830
The result redirected page has a weird error message: Warning

Error loading component: , Component not found.

Comment: If that's all you put I'm not surprised.  How about putting the whole non sef url in?

Comment: Elin is right, you have to put the entire URL in as the URL to be redirected, and then you can use a relative path for the new URL.

Comment: I am not sure what is the non-sef url? I already enabled search engine friendly url and also url rewrite in global config.

Comment: the non-sef url is the one that is: domain.com/?Itemid=something&stuff=blah

the sef url is the one that is: domain.com/about-us

The Redirect component should have a list of all of the url's that have 404 errors (page not found). Just go into them and write the new url as an absolute link: http://www.domain.com/new-url